# Android: How to create EAP wifi configuration programmatically?

Tags: android, configuration, wifi

I know how to create Open/WEP/PSK/PSK2 configuration programmatically.

ex.

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "ssid";
conf.preSharedKey = "\"password\"";
conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        

conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);

conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

int res = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
```

But how do I create one for '802.1x EAP'?
Looking into the source code at:
..\packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\wifi\WifiDialog.java

```
case AccessPoint.SECURITY_EAP:
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
                config.eap.setValue((String) mEapMethod.getSelectedItem());

                config.phase2.setValue((mPhase2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) ? "" :
                        "auth=" + mPhase2.getSelectedItem());
                config.ca_cert.setValue((mEapCaCert.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) ? "" :
                        KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.CA_CERTIFICATE +
                        (String) mEapCaCert.getSelectedItem());
                config.client_cert.setValue((mEapUserCert.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) ? "" :
                        KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.USER_CERTIFICATE +
                        (String) mEapUserCert.getSelectedItem());
                config.private_key.setValue((mEapUserCert.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) ? "" :
                        KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.USER_PRIVATE_KEY +
                        (String) mEapUserCert.getSelectedItem());
                config.identity.setValue((mEapIdentity.length() == 0) ? "" :
                        mEapIdentity.getText().toString());
                config.anonymous_identity.setValue((mEapAnonymous.length() == 0) ? "" :
                        mEapAnonymous.getText().toString());
                if (mPassword.length() != 0) {
                    config.password.setValue(mPassword.getText().toString());
                }
```

Seems to do the work but 'config.eap' is not accessable from my application.

Is there a way to configure EAP types or is it not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered this here:
[How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android)

hth :)

Answer (score 0):

Java Reflection API can be used to create IEEE802.x network with certificate. You can directily create IEEE802.x network connection is earlier version (like 1.6). In latest android the "EnterpriseField" (a inner class) is not directily accessible through program.