# How to implement EAP authenticationin Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to create EAP wifi configuration programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249911/android-how-to-create-eap-wifi-configuration-programmatically)

Is there any API for implementing EAP Authentication in Android ?

Comment: Actually, looking closer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android is a better dupe, but...

Comment: That will not work dear and in AAA logs shows PHASE2 Authentication failed.